# Could not get the DateTime Object for Build TestRun

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Couldn't get the proper `DateTime` value for `StartDate` and `CompletedDate` in Build `TestRun` Object, it only returns the default `DateTime` value (01-01-0001).

**Dll Used:** Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.dll

[image: TestRun object result]

But while accessing the Build `TestRun` through Rest API Url we are getting the date values which i mentioned above.

**TFS Version**: 2018 Update 2

[image: Rest API Result]

**Updated**:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in that request `GetTestRunByQueryAsync()` we will not get the `DateTime` objects (`TestRun` detailed info), we have to make an another call using the `TestRun` Id and `ProjectName` to the method `GetTestRunByIdAsync(ProjectName, RunId)`, then you will get the entire `Build` and `Test` related objects that includes `DateTime` values. Here i have posted the Fiddler response but it worked in code also.

**GetTestRunByQueryAsync() Result:**

[image]

**GetTestRunByIdAsync(ProjectName, RunId) Result:**

[image]